# PictureBox initial image

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Is there a way that you can set all of the picboxes to a initial image when they are loaded? Such as: when you start a round, all the images are set to a image of a card facing down, then when the round starts it shows an image.
EDIT: How do I clear what is in the PicCard.Image?

```
Public Class Form1
Private Cards As New List(Of PictureBox)
Private randomnumber As Integer
Private HowManyCards As Integer

Private Sub SetupCards(numberofcards As Integer)
    ClearGame()
    For i As Integer = 0 To numberofcards

        Dim PicCard As PictureBox = New PictureBox()
        PicCard.Width = 100
        PicCard.Height = 200
        PicCard.Top = 50
        PicCard.Left = 50 + PicCard.Width * i
        Me.Controls.Add(PicCard)
        PicCard.Image = imglistBackOfCard.Images(0)


    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub ClearGame()
    If Cards.Count > 0 Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To Cards.Count - 1
            Me.Controls.Remove(Cards(i))
        Next
    End If
    ' Clear the cards if they were already setup from a previous game.
    Cards.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub RandomCard()
    Randomize()
    randomnumber = Int(Rnd() * imglist1.Images.Count - 1) + 1
End Sub

Public Sub ShowCards(numberofcards As Integer)


    For i As Integer = 0 To numberofcards

        Dim PicCard As PictureBox = New PictureBox()
        RandomCard()
        PicCard.Width = 100
        PicCard.Height = 200
        PicCard.Top = 50
        PicCard.Left = 50 + PicCard.Width * i
        Me.Controls.Add(PicCard)
        PicCard.Image = imglist1.Images(randomnumber)
        PicCard.Tag = randomnumber

        AddHandler PicCard.Click, AddressOf Me.cardflip_click
        Cards.Add(PicCard)

    Next i
End Sub


Private Sub StartGame_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStartGame.Click

    ShowCards(HowManyCards - 1)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    HowManyCards = InputBox("How Many Cards?", "Please Enter")
    SetupCards(Int(howmanycards - 1))
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You dont want to do it that way - every "round" you are creating X number of new picturebox controls.  Why cant some of them be reused? As is, your app is leaking resources badly. The NET `Random` class is much easier to work with than that old legacy function. Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Well, each round there is a different number of pictureboxes.

Comment: Yes, I get that.  So if there was 15 in the last round and only 12 in this one, that means there are 12 that need not be destroyed or created.  Better still, since it is expensive to create controls like that, why not put 15 or whatever the max is on the form and then loop thru them and make however many you need visible and the rest invisible?

Comment: Okay, but back to the question, do you know a way to do that?

Comment: Same way you do the others more or less: assign the image in that  loop where they are created.  Pull the image from another ImageList or use a static one.  You'll need a delay when you reveal the card pick or it will change too quickly

Comment: `Dim PicCard As PictureBox = New PictureBox()` So after this you are saying to do "PicCard.image = imageliststaticimage.images(0)". But if I do that it will just override that in bottom portion of the loop, where I assign the PicCardImage a random image in the other loop.

Comment: I thought you *wanted* a card back image showing at first?

Comment: I do, but if you do PicCard.image = imagebackofcard after you dimension it, it will be overridden by the next loop which sets the PicCard to a random image

Comment: So dont assign the random image in the creation loop!  Do that in some other loop when you *are* ready for the card faces to show.

Comment: BTW another problem with this approach is that there is nothing to prevent the same card from showing twice or more times.  Random does not mean unique.  To avoid that you need to load the images into a List and shuffle it or randomize it

Comment: @Plutonix : I have edited the question to the latest version, but now I have a problem that the initial image will not disappear after I click the button start game